# Is there a way to know reason why moderator declined a flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

I recently flagged the question [Not able to create responsive layout in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223055/not-able-to-create-responsive-layout-in-android)  for spam. The user said there is a screenshot in the link but when I opened the link, I got redirected to some suspicious site and I could not find the screenshot of app.

[image: Here]

All I could see were ads and promotion of the LightShot screen capture tool (and I have AdBlocker enabled).

But when I checked my flags list, the moderator declined the flag:

[image: On question]

I know moderators are always right and I respect them. But how can I know why the flag is not valid so I won't repeat my mistake again?

Comment: Lightshot is the app to take and share the screenshot. The screenshot shared is part of that page, see http://image.prntscr.com/image/78b5c30a255546f5bd38c12302101352.png for a direct link.

Comment: I've moved the screenshot over to the Stack Exchange imgur.com account and embedded it into the question.

Comment: Oh ok got it ,That was the image , that looked more like an ad Thanks and sorry . Also it would be better to add an option  where moderator can add a comment while declining flag .

Comment: We get way too many flags to comment on each and every one, sorry. We already have the option to decline with a custom message, the moderator just opted for a default instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the clarification and sorry for the inconvenience i caused . But there should be an option atleast ask why the flag is not valid  so we wont repeat same mistake again, posting a question here every  time is such a big process.

Comment: I've fallen for that also, where the site that hosted the image looks dodgy as, put it down to experience.

Comment: *I know moderators are always right* - someone finally realises - hurray! :p (*runs away*)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The flag was declined because the post simply is not spam. It clearly is a question.

The link is not suspicious at all; it is the hosting site for the [*Lightshot* screenshot app](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html); the app uploads screenshots to that site. You may have missed the screenshot:

[image: screenshot from the linked page]

Because that hosting site is indeed rather heavy on the advertising *and* because we wouldn't want the image to be lost in the future, I've moved the image over to our own `stack.imgur.com` hosting, and embedded it into the page. After all, image hosting sites come and go all the time, and there is no guarantee that the image is going to be hosted forever by Lightshot.

Comment: I came accross  similar question  by another user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248398/how-to-create-perfect-layout-android#43248398

Comment: @Redman: heh, the image in the new post even contains the *same name* as the other user. :-) Oh, and the text in the layout definition matches the text in the other image.

Answer (score 4):

The op used the 3rd party image hosting instead stack.imgur for showing his screenshot if you can see in his question he mentioned

> Screenshot on small screen is :  http://prntscr.com/eslzc5

The small screen screenshot is there, reason behind for that is, maybe user unable to embed image because of his low rep so he went for 3rd party image hosting.

Comment: Users of any privilege level are always able to upload images. You can't *embed* them until you have a minimum rep level however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I mean to say embed in my answer :)

Comment: An OP usually picks a third-party solution because they simply don't know about the image upload option, or used a screenshot app that includes online hosting. Either way, they can't embed the image, wherever it is hosted.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar thanks but Martijn pieters answer is complete,any way +1

Comment: @Redman Thank you, I just want to point out the info.